# Java Generics capture error "? super capture#1 of ? super T"

Tags: java, generics

This is a simplified, fabricated scenario intended to demonstrate my problem.

I want to create an `interface MarketingScheme<T>` that will have a collection of participants implementing the `interface MarketingCustomers<? super T>`.  As an example, I might have a marketing scheme designed for Vehicles, of which a marketing customer for Cars might be a participant.  I have another interface, `Manufacturer<R> extends MarketingCustomer <R>`, so a manufacturer of cars is also a marketing customer of cars.

My MarketingScheme interface defines a single method, `public void addParticipant(MarketingCustomer<?super T> customer);`. I would expect to be able to add a `MarketingCustomer<Car>` to a `MarketingScheme<Vehicle>`, assuming Car was a subclass of Vehicle. There may be many schemes, so I should be able to add the same manufacturer to a `MarketingScheme<DurableGood>`, assuming `Vehicle extends DurableGood`

If I create a ManufacturerImpl and pass in a MarketingScheme as follows:

```
    public class ManufacturerImpl<R> implements Manufacturer<R>
{
    public ManufacturerImpl(MarketingScheme<? super R> scheme) {
        super();
        scheme.addParticipant(this);
    }
}
```

... I get the error

```
The method addParticipant(MarketingCustomer<? super capture#1-of ? super R>) in the type MarketingScheme<capture#1-of ? super R> is not applicable for the arguments (ManufacturerImpl<R>)
```

I have read up on [Generic Methods](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp04298/) (helperMethods) and tried to implement one, but I could not get it right.  I have considered adding an additional type declarations to  the interfaces, but none of them compiled or seemed appropriate in my model.  I couldn't find any casts that worked inside of my `addParticipant` call either.

My interfaces are defines as follows ...

```
    public interface MarketingScheme<T>
{
    public void addParticipant(MarketingCustomer<? super T> customer);

}
```

```
public interface MarketingCustomer<S>
{

}
```

```
public interface Manufacturer<R> extends MarketingCustomer<R>
{

}
```

Your answers greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type signature of `addParticipant`:

```
public void addParticipant(MarketingCustomer<? extends T> customer);
```

This is because customer's type parameter should be a subclass, not a superclass, of `T`.

Comment: I work alone and don't have a second set of eyes to catch things like that. Thanks to you and everyone who contributes here!

Answer (score 0):

change it for

public interface MarketingScheme <T>
{

public void addParticipant(MarketingCustomer<<? extends T> customer);

}